# Compress app packge

Tags: ios, ipad

I have an app that have a LOT of images (some are in jpeg, others in PNG).
This image must be in bundle because the app need to run offline.

I tried to zip the images but does not make much diference.

I was thinking in compressing the images, but since they have different types will be a lot of work do decode then beside they can't lost quality.

My app has 300mb.

Any ideas ?

**EDIT**

Those images are from are downloaded by a script, my app have an embed sqlite (make by a script too) mapping then.
Most of then are pictures with 600x600 approach.

Comment: What kind of images are they? If not all, can you mimic some of them with Core Graphics?

Comment: I agree, we need more specifics on the types of images and their usages. For instance, if you have hundreds of button images that can be programmatically created (especially with the new stretchableImage attributes) you can eliminate most if not all of this type by utilizing CoreGraphics techniques. If it is a large database of satellite imagery that's another issue that could deal with downloading different geolocated maps for each user at runtime. If it's all a ton of different animation images then sprite sheets. Need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPEG and PNG images are already compressed. Trying to compress them further won't help significantly; it'll just make your application more complicated, and make it take longer to display the images.

Converting PNG images to JPEG, where appropriate, or compressing JPEG images at a lower quality setting, may save you a considerable amount of space.

Comment: Can't convert PNG to JPEG because some images has transparency background. And the client does not approved lose quality. I don't think i will be able to anything =/.

But thanks for the answer my research was pointing to the same result about compressing JPEG or PNG

Comment: Yeah, if you can't change the format or JPEG quality, your hands are basically tied.